# What is the difference of using JdbcTemplate.execute(ConnectionCallback) vs. try with resources?

Tags: spring, jdbc

I'm using QueryDSL (but it's not QueryDSL specific problem) and it need JDBC Connection to work. I must make sure that the connection is properly closed etc.

I consider two options:

Simple

```
try(Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
   //here goes my QueryDSL code
}
```

Using ConnectionCallback

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback<String>() {
    public String doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException {
       //here goes my QueryDSL code
    }     
}
```

What gives me using jdbcTemplate here vs. try with resources? Is this somehow related to transaction handling?

DataSource is acquired from JBoss by JNDI.

Comment: The `JdbcTemplate` (when you don't have transaction configured) already closes the connection for you.

Comment: Try with resources gives me the same.

Comment: Yes, it has done that since Spring 1 it also works on every java version, whereas the resources only work on java 7 or up.